# Difference for eval exec functions in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am still confuse about eval and exac scenario as below;

```
1st scenario: exec ping "stackoverflow.com" -n 1
2nd scenario: eval exec [list ping //nologo "stackoverflow.com" -n 1]
3rd scenario: [list eval exec [list ping //nologo "stackoverflow.com" -n 1]]
```

The questions as below;
1. Difference tree above?
2. what is value number 1?
3. which one is good to use it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Tcl 8.5 (current is 8.6.8), the expansion 
operator `{*}` (which breaks a list 
into its component words) was added, and `eval` is rarely needed except 
when evaluating scripts and script fragments.

With older versions of Tcl, `eval` is used instead of the expansion operator.

With the use of the expansion operator, #2 would become:

```
exec {*}[list ping /nologo "stackoverflow.com" -n 1]
```

There's nothing wrong with your #1, but there are a couple of common
patterns with the usage of `exec` where #2 is more useful.

a) Saving the command to be executed allows you to reuse it for a retry
   or for debugging.

b) Commands can be built in a dynamic fashion.

```
foreach {host} [list stackoverflow.com stack_typo_exchange.com superuser.com] {
  set cmd [list ping /nologo $host -n 1]
  try {
    exec {*}$cmd
  } on error {err res} {
    puts "ERROR: exec: $cmd"
    puts "       result: $res"
  }         
}
```

Older versions of Tcl would use the `catch` command:

```
if { [catch {eval exec $cmd}] } {
   puts "ERROR: exec: $cmd"
}
```

Your #3 is (usually) not correct code.  It is creating a list out of the return value from `eval exec`.

References: [Tcl / argument expansion](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm), [try](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/try.htm), [catch](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/catch.htm), [exec](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm)

Comment: Thanks Brad. Actually, I just want if the computer fail or denied access to ping that just auto cancel and dont display error message including windows message like denied access massage.